# Fibers / Coroutines vs Delimited Continuations

Tags: theory, coroutine, fiber, delimited-continuations

So I read a paper about concurrent work stealing deques here: http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3872.pdf. They mention "Child-Stealing vs Continuation Stealing" and they say that child stealing can require unbounded stack space to hold yet-to-be executed tasks unlike continuation stealing which is a constant factor of P=#processors.

I have a theoretical questions on the difference between fibers / coroutines and delimited continuations. First, I accept that coroutines and fibers are pretty much equivalent, but are fibers also equivalent to continuations? I have a sneaking suspicion that what I'm about to implement is fundamentally wrong (ie. replacing threads with fibers, and not actually implementing a version that doesn't require unbounded memory).

Answer (score 0):

At the conceptual level, "stackful coroutines" is equivalent with "one-shot delimited continuation" or "one-short continuation" in terms of their expressivity, and fibers means stackful coroutines with a (often plugable) scheduler, [see](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/250RTS/archive/roberto-ierusalimschy/revisiting-coroutines.pdf).